# Matching empty and non-empty lists with a single pattern match?

Tags: erlang

I have the following function, which takes a bunch of lists in a map (currently 2), and returns lists that only contain the first element of each of them:

```
transform_remove_history(#{
                 prematchVars := [#{vars := LatestPrematchVars} | _],
                 vars := [#{vars := LatestVars} | _]} 
              = GameState) ->
    GameState#{prematchVars := [LatestPrematchVars], vars := [LatestVars]};

transform_remove_history(GameState) ->
    GameState.
```

*(The map has many other elements, not just these two lists!)*

The problem is that if either `prematchVars` or `vars` is an empty list then the first pattern does not match and neither list will be updated.

If I have `N` lists then the patterns I'd have to write would be all the possible combinations (that is 2^N if my maths is right... well, a lot of combinations anyway).

I can write a helper function for the list transformation, but I was wondering if there is an efficient way of expressing this as a single pattern match in Erlang?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `maps:map/2` to handle each map element and produce a new map:

```
transform_remove_history(GameState) ->
    maps:map(fun(_,[]) ->
                     [];
                (K,[H|_]) when K =:= prematchVars; K =:= vars ->
                     [H];
                (_,V) ->
                     V
             end, GameState).
```

The mapping function takes two arguments, key and value. If the value is `[]`, just return it; if it's a list of one or more elements, return a list consisting of only the head; otherwise just return the value as is. If you need to match only certain keys, you can do that by specifying matches for the first argument of the mapping function.

Comment: Ah, beat me to it. :-)

Comment: Forgot to mention that the map has many other elements, not just these two lists.

Comment: That's not a problem, since the third clause of the mapping function just passes all other elements through.

Comment: It is a problem if an additional element is a list, which I don't want to truncate...

Comment: maps:with/2 to the rescue?... :)

Comment: @GaborKulcsar: that's why I pointed out that you can also match the keys if you need to match/truncate only certain lists. The first argument to the mapping function is the key.

Comment: @GaborKulcsar: for example, you could change the head of the second clause to `(K,[H|_]) when K =:= prematchVars; K =:= vars ->`, which would make the clause apply to only those two keys.

Comment: @GaborKulcsar Your game data lists should exist in a *different layer* of your data structure, then. Your data looks like a pile of accumulated stuff you found laying around your system, not like *a structure*. Change that and everything else gets a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Your choice of data structure is a bit odd. This sounds, basically, like you want to do a map operation (as in `lists:map/2`) over an arbitrary stack of lists.

It appears that given any particular list you want to:

```
truncate([])    -> [];
truncate([H|_]) -> [H].
```

And then you want this to happen over all the elements in your map. That gives us a map-friendly version of the truncate function, and a call to `maps:map/2`:

```
truncate(_, [])    -> [];
truncate(_, [H|_]) -> [H].

Truncated = maps:map(fun truncate/2, Map).
```

Or something *very similar* depending on how your actual data structure looks. As of the discussion about the list operations over maps last week on the ML, most of them are implemented as actual list operations over the output of `maps:to_list/1` anyway, so there may be no advantage in keeping your `GameState` structure in a map at all.

---

**Concerning specific subsets of keys**

If you are absolutely *forced* to deal with a data structure that amounts to a big thoughtless pile of crap all stuffed into a single map (a rather common anti-pattern encountered in legacy code written initially by Erlang newcomers) you can save yourself a bit generating a list of keys and prefacing your operation by using `maps:with/2`:

```
Keys = [foo, bar, baz],
Partial = maps:with(Keys, Map),
Truncated = maps:map(fun truncate/2, Partial).
```

In this way you can only deal with the parts you care about, while leaving the big blob of unrelated crap out of the operation you want to perform.

Long-term, though, the best way to make your life easier (and the life of a future maintainer) is to start abstracting your one-huge-map structure into an ADT of its own. Create a module called `game_data`, write functions that equate to getters and setters, behind those functions you can make your data look however you want *and change the layout as needed* without causing the changes to wash all over the entire codebase each time.

Comment: This is what I meant by a "helper function" :)

Comment: @GaborKulcsar I know. The fact that *two* different functional programmers are giving you nearly *the same* solution should tell you something about functional idioms, data structures, and how they work together. Anyway, I *named my function* and Steve wrote exactly *the same function* with one extra clause to pass non-lists through, but did it anonymously. I like named functions more most of the time, but that is just style, it doesn't change what is happening in the code. The key problem with your data is its structure.

Comment: Interestingly, I found that Erlang makes it extremely easy to deal with the whole state being in a single map: I can easily pattern match on parts which I need in the header of functions, and return the modified bits with another pattern match in an update. Since this whole stuff sits in a `gen_server`'s state, I'm not sure how would it work in the way that you are suggesting. Maybe I could put these two lists in their own sub-map in the state map.

Comment: @GaborKulcsar This last sentence you wrote is basically what I am getting at. The state of the gen_server can be held whatever way is convenient -- you should be structuring the data so that related data elements are siblings. Why would, say, a port number, a socket reference, a hostname, last username, current username, current game state, and some random user data be on the same level of a map? That's insane. This is a functional language, and it will be easiest to leverage functional paradigms if you structure your data in ways that lend themselves to that.